# Finding the length of a half of a side of a triangle (can be unequal half)

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

**The Question**

> [image]

Given, $AB$, $AC$ and $BC$. $DE$ is parallel to $BC$. The area ratio between $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle BDEC$ is also provided. How can I find $AD$?

**My Understanding**

I know that $\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AE}{AC}
=\frac{DE}{BC}$ in this problem.

Comment: What do you know about similar triangles?

Comment: I know from the triangle (AD/AB=AE/AC=DE/BC) . But I can't use it properly. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: what else is given in the problem as if this is the problem then we can't find the the side length exactly

Comment: That's a good start. Note that the area ratio of $\triangle ADE$ to $\triangle ABC$ is equal to the square of the ratio of $AD$ to $AB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

Calling that if a triangle (and any 2D polygon) is scaled by a factor $\alpha$ then its surface is scaled by a factor $\alpha^2$ then we have that \begin{equation}
ADE=\left(\dfrac{AD}{AB}\right)^2\cdot ABC.
\end{equation}
Also, we can write the surface $ABC$ using the ratio $ADE/BDEC$ given in the following way:
\begin{equation}
ABC=ADE+ADE\cdot\left(\dfrac{BDEC}{ADE}\right)=ADE\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{BDEC}{ADE}\right).
\end{equation}
Joinng both equations we have that
\begin{equation}
ADE=\left(\dfrac{AD}{AB}\right)^2ABC=ADE\left(\dfrac{AD}{AB}\right)^2\left(1+\dfrac{BDEC}{ADE}\right).
\end{equation}
Now, since $ADE\not=0$ (otherwise, the exercise is trivial!) we get that
\begin{equation}
1=\left(\dfrac{AD}{AB}\right)^2\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{BDEC}{ADE}\right).
\end{equation}
Solving for $AD$ we end up with \begin{equation}
AD=\dfrac{AB}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{BDEC}{ADE}}}.
\end{equation}
Note: Notice that although we divided by $ADE$ in some equations, the final formula does not depend on its value (but in its ratio with $BDEC$, which is given).

Answer (score 1):

Let AB=c, BC=a and AC=b. Draw altitude from A, mark its foot as H and it's intersection with DE as G. Let the ratio of areas is:

$\frac{ADE}{BCDE}=k$

We have:

$\frac{ADE}{BCDE}+1=\frac{ADE+BCDE=ABC}{BCDE}=k+1$

$S=ABC=\frac{AH\times BC}2$

$ADE=\frac{DE\times AG}2$

$$\frac{\frac{AH\times BC}2}{\frac{AH\times BC}2-\frac{DE\times AG}2}=k+1$$

$\Rightarrow \frac S{S-DE\times AG}=k+1 \Rightarrow DE\times AG=S\big(1-\frac 1{k+1}\big)=\frac{S\cdot k}{k+1}$

$S=ABC=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$

$\Rightarrow AH=\frac {2S} a$

Also:

$\frac{AG}{AH}=\frac{DE}{BC}\Rightarrow \frac{DE}{AG}=\frac {BC}{AH}$

Now we have following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}\frac{DE}{AG}=\frac {BC}{AH}=\frac{a^2}{2S}\\DE\times AG=\frac{S\cdot k}{k+1}\end{cases}$

Solving this system gives DE and AG.Now we have:

$$\frac {AD}{c}=\frac{AG}{AH}$$

$$AD=\frac{c\cdot AG}{AH}$$